# JWT in WSO2 APIM 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to explore the JWT feature of WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 which passes specific attributes like enduser/subscriber and application details to the backend from WSO2 API Gateway. I wanted to know where can i find the default JWT generator jar or class: "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator". I checked in the dropins folder under <Product_Home>/repository/components but didn't find.

The default JWT generator class sends details something like below. I want to know, can we customize to send the user/subscriber roles as well along with the below details. Need suggestions about this feature.

```
{
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier": "Unlimited",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/version": "1.0.0",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/keytype": "PRODUCTION",
  "iss": "wso2.org/products/am",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationname": "DefaultApplication",
  "keytype": "PRODUCTION",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduser": "john@carbon.super",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduserTenantId": "-1234",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/subscriber": "john",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/tier": "Unlimited",
  "scope": "order_pizza",
  "exp": "1597753868867",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationid": "4",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/usertype": "Application_User",
  "consumerKey": "e5syg4saM5hAxDZkUYA1gy2hyy0a",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/apicontext": "/pizzashack/1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find info about customising JWTs and passing end-user attributes to backend using JWTs in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/#passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have gone through this link. I want to know where can i find the custom JWT generator class/jar that comes with WSO2 APIM and also want to know how can i send user roles as well with the custom JWT class.

Comment: This is the class - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/token/JWTGenerator.java

Comment: Roles come under user claims of the user. So you can change the structure of it - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/token/JWTGenerator.java#L145

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Pubci. Is this default JWT generator class/jar also present under WSO2 Product_Home? And, i am not able to understand how to change the structure of user claims to send user roles. Do you mean I will have to create a custom JWT class for that? Also, please tell me if there is some method like validationContext.getValidationInfoDTO().getEndUserName() that will give user roles? Appreciate your help.